Plotshape signal is being triggered even when there’s no existing position
I have this that triggers with "Hit Sl" but the first bar should not hit because there is no open buying positon in the lower timeframe. and if i have an existing position can I verify that it really met the condition in the lower timeframe? Is this possible to do?


Use a strategy() instead of the study() and Pine will manage your positions for you otherwise you have to do it manually which you really don't want. (Just like when you want to hammer a nail, you don't want to work on the hammer instead). You can still draw fancy characters in a strategy, just like in a study and never execute a trade.
